# Select li elements from ul with xpath

Tags: html, python-3.x, xpath, lxml

I'm starting with `XPATH` from `lxml` on `Python3` and I'm unable to get the right sintaxis to select all `li` elements with content of a `ul`. I'm trying with this structure:

```
<body>
 <div> ..... </div>
 <div> ..... </div>
 <div id="div-A">
  <div id="subdiv-1">
   <form> ... </form>
   <div> ..... </div>
   <div> ..... </div>
   <ul>
    <li>
     <div id="div-1">
      <div> ..... </div>
      <div> ..... </div>
      <div id="subdiv-1">
       <a class="name">
        <span>
          ....text1....
        </span>
       </a>
      </div>
      <div id="subdiv-2">
       <div class="class-1">
        <div class="subClass-1">
         <div> ....text2.... </div>
        </div>
        <span class="subClass-2">
         ....text3....
        </span>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </li>
    ... x23...
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

My goal it's to be able to get **text1**, **text2** and **text3**.

So first, I try to get all `li` elements with their content:

```
content = html_response.content
fixed_content = fromstring(content)  # parse the HTML and correct malformed HTML
items = fixed_content.xpath('//ul/li/*')
```

And pass `items` to a function with a for loop to iterate over the 23 `li` elements. Now I try to get the texts, so:

```
for item in items:
 text1 = item.xpath('/div[@id="div-1"]/div[@id="subdiv-1"]/a[@class="name"]/span').text_content()
 text2 = item.xpath('/div[@id="div-1"]/div[@id="subdiv-2"]/div[@class="class-1"]/div[@class="subClass-1"]/div').text_content()
 text3 = item.xpath('/div[@id="div-1"]/div[@id="subdiv-2"]/div[@class="class-1"]/div[@class="subClass-2"]/span[@class="subClass-2"]').text_content()
```

But I get on all cases an empty result with no content. What I'm doing wrong?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code to get required output:

```
items = fixed_content.xpath('//ul/li//span | //ul/li//div[@class="subClass-1"]')
for item in items:
    item.text_content().strip()
```

The output is

```
'....text1....'
'....text2....'
'....text3....'
```

or

```
items = fixed_content.xpath('//ul/li') 
for item in items:
    text1 = item.xpath('.//a[@class="name"]/span')[0].text_content().strip()
    text2 = item.xpath('.//div[@class="subClass-1"]')[0].text_content().strip()
    text3 = item.xpath('.//span[@class="subClass-2"]')[0].text_content().strip()
```

if you want to get each text node as variable

Comment: Thanks, so my mistake was on '//ul/li/*' and not start with the dot on "xpath('.  " :)

Comment: `'//ul/li/*'` should select *all child nodes of `li` nodes*, but not `li` nodes. If XPath starts with dot it mean that you want to search for child/descendant of current node (`item` in your case) while no dot means to search in a whole HTML DOM...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Your xpath queries seem to give the wanted output for me. text1, text2 and text3 results when writing them out completely. Using the string() method you are able to select the inner text value of the found element:

```
//ul/li/div[@id="div-1"]/div[@id="subdiv-1"]/a[@class="name"]/span/string(),
//ul/li/div[@id="div-1"]/div[@id="subdiv-2"]/div[@class="class-1"]/div[@class="subClass-1"]/div/string(),
//ul/li/div[@id="div-1"]/div[@id="subdiv-2"]/div[@class="class-1"]/span[@class="subClass-2"]/string()
```

Does writing them out and using the string() method not provide the expected text1-3 values for you?

Comment: Yes, but I think my problem was not doing the string at once. I had '//ul/li/*' instead of '//ul/li' and on the for loop, I didn't start with the dot " xpath('. " as Andersson pointed. Thanks for your answer anyway :)

Comment: Ah I see, my bad. Glad you did get it resolved though! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
[i.strip() for i in tree.xpath('//ul//div[@class="subClass-1"]//text()|//ul//span//text()') if i.strip()]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.